# Iterative DNS client using DatagramSockets

Tags: java, dns

My homework is to implement an iterative DNS client using UDP. I can't find any example how to ask a DNS server for e.g MX record? How to check if answer is authoritative? Any example code?

Comment: Google, and, just so you know, homework is about learning to code, not learning to cut and paste.

Answer (score 1):

The format of requests and responses is defined in [RFC-1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035). The following [link](http://www.netfor2.com/dns.htm) contains just the relevant information in a more readable format.

See also this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/173187/what-does-a-dns-request-look-like) on ServerFault which suggests using tools like WireShark to inspect the data coming and going over the wire for debug purposes.